# Client can't get cookies with Identity

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-identity

I'm writing a SPA application with ASP.NET Core and Angular. I'm using CORS to communicate between frontend and backend. I found I can't get authorized after login, and there is no cookies in client side. I've been stuck for 2 days now, please help me.

In `startup.cs`, I have:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(...)      
        services.AddDbContext<TaskMatrixContext>(...);
        services.AddControllers(...)
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {...}); 
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser,IdentityRole().
                 AddEntityFrameworkStores<TaskMatrixContext>();
        services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie();
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {...});
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {...});  
         ...
    } 

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors("AllowMyOrigin");
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

This is my `AccountController`:

```
[HttpPost("/login")]
public async Task<ActionResult<LoginDto>> Login(LoginDto model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            model.IsLoggedIn = true;
        }

        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            model.IsLockedOut = true;
            model.RedirectUrl = "/account/lockedout";
        }
    }

    return model;
}
```

In my frontend:

```
login(dto:LoginInput):Observable<LoginResult> {
    return this.http.post<LoginResult>
                (this.baseUrl+'/login',dto).pipe(
                    tap(...)
                );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another several days' study, I found we can't use Identity Core to realize authentication in REST Api. We should use JWT to generate tokens and verify it. The recommended tutorial for frontend is:
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/14/aspnet-core-3-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management
for backend:
https://dev.to/moe23/asp-net-core-5-rest-api-authentication-with-jwt-step-by-step-140d

Comment: Rather than providing just the links. It is best to include information on package to use that works with REST API and sample code that can help developers with similar issue.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `withCredentials` option:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

In your frontend:

```
login(dto:LoginInput):Observable<LoginResult> {
    return this.http.post<LoginResult>
                (this.baseUrl+'/login',dto,{withCredentials: true}).pipe(
                    tap(...)
                );
}
```

The same should be done for every request that requires authentication cookie